# Dualboot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on Dell Precision M3800

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I'm trying to dualboot Win10 and Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on my Dell Precision M3800.

Dell M3800 Specs:
i7 Quad Core 2.30GHz
16 Gb Ram
512 Gb Full Mini SSD
1TB HDD
NVidia Quadro K1100

Boot settings are set to legacy. Whenever I boot from a usb, I press F12 to open the boot options and select the USB option i.e. I don't boot using the EUFI option that is also available.

What I want to do is have two partitions on the SSD, one for Windows and one for Ubuntu. I can successfully create the partitions and install Windows, but for some reason the installer places the windows bootloader on the HDD.

After several unsuccessful attempts to fix this, I continued anyway and installed Ubuntu on the second partition of the SSD. I first tried just using a single partition set to root (/), but the installer notified me that it could not install the boatloader at this target. Then I tried using four separate partitions: 1Gb for bootloader, 30Gb for root (/), 10Gb for swap and the remainder for home (/home).

The installer completed successfully, but I could not boot into Windows or Ubuntu.

The HDD is listed as sda and the SSD as sdb. Must the bootloader be loaded onto sda? Could having two harddrives be the cause of this problem?

I've been struggling for the past few days and any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Ok, I've made progress. I reinstalled Windows and Ubuntu using their EUFI installers and with my bios settings set to EUFI. Now I can boot into Windows using the Windows Boot Loader EUFI, but for Ubuntu it boots in Grub. I can then list the partitions as follows:

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02^beta2-9

grub> ls
(hd0) (hd1) (hd1,gpt5) (hd1,gpt4) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1)
```

Using the following code, I can get the normal grub menu and boot into either Ubuntu or Windows:

```
grub>  set boot=(hd1,gpt5)
grub>  set prefix=(hd1,gpt5)/boot/grub
grub>  insmod normal  
grub>  normal
```

In Ubuntu, I ran boot repair and also tried reinstalling grub as follows:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
```

The installation is successful, but everytime I boot, I get the command line grub menu. It also just stays there, and does not automatically boot into Ubuntu.

How can I configure grub to boot to the normal screen, and then automatically boot into Ubuntu?

Comment: Is Windows installed in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? You need to install Ubuntu in the same boot mode. Default installs of grub is to sda, with BIOS to the MBR and with UEFI to the ESP - efi system partition. And if two drives both drive need to be gpt partitioned if UEFI. If BIOS Windows has to have MBR, but if a separate drive for Ubuntu it can be gpt or MBR. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info